# Is QED asymptotically free in lower dimensions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, asymptotics

It is well-known that QED (=quantum electrodynamics) is NOT asymptotically free in spacetime dimension $4$.

However, I wonder if it becomes asymptotically free in lower dimensions, such as $2+1$ spacetime.

By asymptotic freedom, I mean that the sign of the $\beta$-function is negative for all sufficiently small magnitude of the coupling constant.

Comment: Every theory converges to a free theory as its coupling constant converges to zero (not considering non-perturbative solutions scaling as $1/g$). Didn't you mean coupling constant converging to zero in some high energy limit instead?

Comment: @dennismoore94 Oh...I am sorry that I was not specific enough. I corrected the problem.

Comment: [Ref](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.01544).